# Mysql IF IN (Select) no esta sirviendo

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema, tengo esta consulta

```
select if (id in ( 
                  select valor 
                  from tabla_variable 
                  where nombre = 'no_id'),null,id) as id 
from tabla_id
```

```
tabla_id 

id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

tabla_variable

```
id_variable | nombre | valor |
1             no_id    4,5
```

esperaba que me devolviera esto

```
id
1
2
3
null
null
6
7
```

pero me esta devolviendo esto

```
id
1
2
3
null
5
6
7
```

me esta tomando solo el primer numero y necesito que lo tome como si la consulta como tal fuera asi

```
select if(id in (4,5),null,id) as id 
from tabla_id
```

Comment: Si tienes los valores como un string que contiene todos los ID, esa consulta no te funciona (la BD no tiene por qué decidir mirar una lista separada por comas y ver si un ID está ahí). Me sorprende que funcione para el 4. Esa consulta como la tienes, funcionaría si la tabla tabla_variable estuviese normalizada y tuviese un registro para el valor 4 y otro para el valor 5

Comment: @ReiKagene tu campo valor de la tabla_variable es de tipo varchar? siempre va a tener dos valores?

Comment: es tipo longtext, y si siempre va a tener dos valores, incluso puede llegar a tener mas

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de que siempre tengas dos valores en el campo valor puedes hacer uso de la  función **SUBSTRING_INDEX()** que te permite extraer los números separados por la coma, entonces la consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
select if (t1.id in (SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.valor,',',1), 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.valor,',',-1)),null,t1.id) as ID
from tabla_id t1, tabla_variable  t2 where t2.nombre='no_id'
```

La sintaxis de la función es: **SUBSTRING_INDEX(cadena,delimitador,contador).**

La cadena vendría a ser tu campo valor, el delimitador en este caso sería la coma y
el contador se debe especificar. Si es positivo te va a devolver los valores de la izquierda de la coma contando desde la izquierda. Si es negativo te va a devolver los valores de la derecha de la coma contando desde la derecha.

Como "siempre" va a tener dos valores tu campo, el contador sería 1 para capturar el número de la izquierda **(4)** y -1 para el número de la derecha **(5)**.

Pero si tu campo tuviera mas de dos valores por ejemplo **'4,5,6,7...'** los valores que retornarías sería **4** y **7**. Si tu ingresas en el contador -2 te retornaría **6,7** o si ingresas 2 te retornaría **4,5**.

Como mencionabas que incluso puede tener mas valores tu campo. En tu consulta al usar IN éste no te toma como una cadena lo que tienes en tu campo "valor", en lugar de usar IN podrías usar la función **FIND_IN_SET()** que sí te devuelve todos los valores en el que está presente el id dentro una cadena quedando la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
select if (find_in_set (t1.id,t2.valor),null,t1.id) as ID from tabla_id t1, 
tabla_variable  t2 where t2.nombre='no_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Me cuesta un poco trabajo saber que deseas hacer, pero lo que observo que quieres validar de la tabla tabla_id  hacia la tabla tabla_variable por la llave id si la columna nombre contiene el campo 'no_id':

```
select if((select nombre from tabla_variable AS tb2 where tb2.id = tb1.id) = 'no_id',null,id) as id from tabla_id AS tb1
```

Te sugiero que uses Alias a tus tablas para no tener ambigüedades al intentar devolver datos.

Comment: lo que necesito hacer es sacar todos los id, menos lo que estan en la celda de la columna valor de la fila con el nombre de "no_id" de la tabla variable el cual no posee relacion con la tabla de tabla_id, por eso lo utilizo llamando el nombre de esa celda " nombre = 'no_id' " pero no esta tomando todo el numero de la celda si no que solo esta tomando el primero como si fuera asi  select if(id in (4),null,id) as id from tabla_id   y no asi select if(id in (4,5),null,id) as id from tabla_id por eso me temo que un alias no ayudaria